# Get correct splash image programmatically from Images.xcassets?

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, xcasset

I want to show splash screen image as background of the app too. But the problem is i using Images.xcassets for LaunchImage. Now when i give name of the launch image in given below code it return me image for retina device(@2x) but not for iphone 6, 6+ or 5s.

Comment: You really should be using a launch nib and not launch images any more.

Comment: that answer is old and is not working for me.